# How to toggle a div element between two images when click two submit buttons in a wordpress loop?

Tags: loop, jquery

How to toggle a div element between two images in a wordpress loop when click two submit buttons simultaneously? I have one div, 1st image should select when i click on the first submit button and then 2nd image while click 2nd button. Now this is coming only for the first post.

```
<div class="totart">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="first_image" id="img1" style="display: block;">
    <?php   the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
         <div class="second_image" id="img2" style="display: none;"> 
             <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) :    
                   MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');   
           endif; ?></div>
        <input type="button" value="" id="btn1" style="background:yellow;" />
       <input type="button" value="" id="btn2" style="background:green;"/>


            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>


        </div>
```

jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting forms by accident
    $('#img1').show();
    $('#img2').hide();
});
$('#btn2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting forms by accident
    $('#img1').hide();
    $('#img2').show();
});
```

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want this for all your posts and as of now it is working only for the first one in the loop?

Comment: @kidakaka  exactly .now its working only for the first post. From the next post onwards its giving the default image only. Not changing on clicking the 2nd button.

Answer (score 0):

The ID has to be unique for all the posts, so I would suggest that you concatenate btn1-ID> in your code.

That and change your jquery selector code. That should do the trick!

Comment: i didnt get u. how to do that. pl help

Comment: try $(input[id^='btn1']).click(....